# powershell export-csv to force write if file is currently open

Tags: powershell

I have a successful script that takes up some data analysis from local machine and exports a csv file at the end. No issues there.

Mn problem is that if someone has that file open, and at the same time script is writing to the file (I have -append switch), nothing gets written so I lose the data for that particular computer.

Any ideas how to force write the file even if it is open or in use? Thank you.

Functional export of existing array:

```
$NewCSVObject | Export-CSV '<fullpath>\CleanupResults.csv' -noType -Append
```

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer to this question. It'll depend greatly upon *how* that other user (program) has opened the file handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting that file to Read-Only?  That will prevent anyone else from getting an opportunistic lock on it, and you can still append data to it by using the -Force switch.

Comment: Perfect. I marked the file read-only and applied -Force with export command and tested with file being open and it still overwrote the file. Great solution.
Thank you very much mjolinor. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do that. If another a process already has exclusive access to the file, just pick another a file to write into.

Trying to shoehorn data into a file someone else is messing around is asking for trouble. For example, the other process might write changes into the file. Thus your input is going to be replaced with whatever data the other process has.

Comment: Actually system writing/appending file is the only one having write access. Everyone else has read to copy or glance at data. Problem if anyone having file open even as read-only is not letting process append the file. Only gives me option to force overwrite as that is important tasks than anyone looking at the data and having file open.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this with the help of [PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) by removing the lock on the file remotely before writing to it.

Example of how to close a file on remote machine using PSFile command:
PSFile.exe \\remotecomputername "C:\File.CSV" -c

You could also test for a file lock before you try to write to it and have logic around that.
This thread has a good example of testing for a lock.
[How can I force a Powershell script to wait overwriting a file until another process is finished reading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738236/how-can-i-force-a-powershell-script-to-wait-overwriting-a-file-until-another-pro)